# GITHUB weird contributors after transfer

Tags: github

I moved my gitlab repo to github and weird things, a new contributors appears (Landris18 on the link at the end).

I wonder how could I remove that without wiping all my repo ? (I need to keep a track on commits, releases etc..)

https://github.com/edissyum/opencaptureforinvoices/graphs/contributors

Thanks

Comment: Users are identified via their email adress. Your repository must contain commits with the "committer" marks as the email adress that this user uses.

Comment: Update: it seems some of your (?) commits are committed with the email adress "Vous@exemple.com".

Comment: Is it possible to find the commit messages in question ? And if yes, could I delete them to remove this "contributor" ?

Comment: Sadly it could be possible...

Comment: Just click on the number of commits on the contributors page (or [here](https://github.com/edissyum/opencaptureforinvoices/commits?author=Landris18)) and you see exactly which commits are attributed to that user. To remove them from your repository you'd need to rewrite history (which makes your repository no longer compatible with earlier clones of it).